# Getting superuser access through ADB

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I've started working on little something, not too much, but I keep getting stuck.

`echo Look at your phone, you must grant superuser perms.
adb shell "su -c stop"
if NOT %errorlevel% == 0 goto exit
pause`

So, if someone doesn't grant superuser access, it's not going to exit, it just continues, so if he grants it after the command times out, he has to restart the script.
How do I write it so it repeats until the device is granted su permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will loop until `su` succeeds:

```
:noroot
adb shell "su 0 id" | findstr "uid=0(root)" || goto noroot
```

As a side note, I was always puzzled by people trying to supply `-c` as a parameter for android `su` command. According to [`su` command source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/su.c), the proper format is `su [uid[,gid[,group1]...] [cmd]]`

Comment: Sorry, new to adb. If I understood correctly, without the -c parameter it should work fine?

Comment: It depends on the version of `su` binary you are trying to use - if it is based on the standard Android code I linked - the 1st parameter has to be UID (i.e. `0` for `root`) instead of `-c`.